# "Docker Image" build fails due to failure in "JupyterLab" installation

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jupyter-lab

I am trying to build a docker image for using a package named as Automated Recommendation Tool. As per their docker workflow I installed docker on my Ubuntu OS and then tried to build the docker image. Following is the command that I executed -

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 \
    docker build -f docker/Dockerfile \
    --pull \
    --no-cache \
    -t jbei/art .
```

After running for a while I got the following error -
`=> ERROR [jupyter-install 1/1] RUN set -ex  && poetry install      --n  130.5s`

It automatically continued running and later on stopped by giving following output -

```
#13 129.9 - `minimize`: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified
#13 129.9 during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab's overall
#13 129.9 performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very memory
#13 129.9 intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish successfully in
#13 129.9 low-memory environments.
#13 129.9 
#13 130.0 An error occurred.
#13 130.0 RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
#13 130.0 See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-c399mxqe.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -ex  && poetry install      --no-dev     --extras "docker jupyter"      --no-root     --no-interaction     -vv  && rm -rf $ART_USER/.cache/  && jupyter lab build  && jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager  && find ${ART_CODE} -name __pycache__ | xargs rm -rf]: exit code: 1
```

Anyone experienced in building Docker Images, Please help me.
Following are my system specifications -

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS                           
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-37-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: HP
  Hardware Model: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec1xxx
```

Docker Version -

```
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

Update:
Following is the complete output of the jupyter lab build command -

```
#10 39.59 + rm -rf artuser/.cache/
#10 39.59 + jupyter lab build
#10 40.91 [LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 3.4.2
#10 40.91 [LabBuildApp] Building in /usr/local/art/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
#10 41.26 [LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
#10 41.28-Build failed.
#10 122.8 Troubleshooting: If the build failed due to an out-of-memory error, you
#10 122.8 may be able to fix it by disabling the `dev_build` and/or `minimize` options.
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 If you are building via the `jupyter lab build` command, you can disable
#10 122.8 these options like so:
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 You can also disable these options for all JupyterLab builds by adding these
#10 122.8 lines to a Jupyter config file named `jupyter_config.py`:
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 c.LabBuildApp.minimize = False
#10 122.8 c.LabBuildApp.dev_build = False
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 If you don't already have a `jupyter_config.py` file, you can create one by
#10 122.8 adding a blank file of that name to any of the Jupyter config directories.
#10 122.8 The config directories can be listed by running:
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 jupyter --paths
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 Explanation:
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 - `dev-build`: This option controls whether a `dev` or a more streamlined
#10 122.8 `production` build is used. This option will default to `False` (i.e., the
#10 122.8 `production` build) for most users. However, if you have any labextensions
#10 122.8 installed from local files, this option will instead default to `True`.
#10 122.8 Explicitly setting `dev-build` to `False` will ensure that the `production`
#10 122.8 build is used in all circumstances.
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 - `minimize`: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified
#10 122.8 during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab's overall
#10 122.8 performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very memory
#10 122.8 intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish successfully in
#10 122.8 low-memory environments.
#10 122.8 
#10 122.8 An error occurred.
#10 122.8 RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
#10 122.8 See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-iguri15x.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -ex  && poetry install      --no-dev     --extras "docker jupyter"      --no-root     --no-interaction     -vv  && rm -rf $ART_USER/.cache/  && jupyter lab build  && jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager  && find ${ART_CODE} -name __pycache__ | xargs rm -rf]: exit code: 1
```

From these lines I can see that it is suggesting to do the following changes in my jupyter lab build command in the Dockerfile -

```
jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False
```

Will this help, or should I first check the log files which I am unable to locate as the image is not built.

Comment: Does the mentioned log file /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-c399mxqe.log contain anything useful? (docker cp should be able to copy it out of the container since I assume it's stored there)

Comment: I tried to copy the file but got the following error - 
```
(base) vaibhav@vaibhav-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Laptop-15-ec1xxx:~/MyDrive$ docker cp /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-iguri15x.log
"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
 docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have updated the question description with complete output of the jupyter lab build command. PLease check the update as I want to know whether I should go with the suggestions provided in the output lines.

Comment: Steps `jupyter lab build  && jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` are likely not needed if you are using JupyterLab 3.0, so you could just remove them.

Comment: @krassowski I tried your suggestion and have got the following error -
#22 42.46 + pip install ipywidgets COPY notebooks /usr/local/art/notebooks
#22 43.71 ERROR: Invalid requirement: '/usr/local/art/notebooks'
#22 43.71 Hint: It looks like a path. File '/usr/local/art/notebooks' does not exist.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c set -ex  && pip install jupyterlab jupyterlab-git  && pip install ipywidgets COPY notebooks ${ART_CODE}/notebooks]: exit code: 1

usr/local folder in Computer Folder has no folder as art/notebooks. Do I need to create one manually?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what ` /usr/local/art/notebooks` is. Looks like something specific to the docker recipe you are using.